# Trying to show PDF in Lightning web component in iFrame but it does not render the PDF file

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter, getcontentaspdf

I am trying to display a pdf file using Base64data in the Lightning Web component, the PDF Viewer renders but it does not get the PDF file in it.

here's my HTML:

```
<template if:true={showModal}>
        <c-modal show-modal={showModal} is-large="true" onclosemodal={handleCloseModal}>
            <iframe id="pdfFrame" src="/resource/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" width="100%" height="600" class="pdfFrame" onload={loadpdf}></iframe>
        </c-modal>
</template>
```

Here's my JS controller to load PDF :

```
loadpdf(event){
        alert(this.pdfData);
        this.template.querySelector('pdfFrame').contentWindow.postMessage(this.pdfData,'*');    
    }
```

in LoadPdf alert statement, the pdf data is coming just fine, the pdf viewer also renders fine like below but without the actual file :

[image]

is the code to postMessage in iFrame correct here?

Using [this GitHub library.](https://github.com/kumarrk21/PDFViewer)

Comment: By any chance, can you help me with the download and print button on the viewer?

Comment: @gs650x yes, do you have a code you are trying to work with?

Comment: let me create a new thread and will post the question link here

Comment: ok also are you creating contentDocument for this PDF? if so, it is very easy to get download link

Comment: actually, I am not creating a content document, I am generating the PDF on the fly and then displaying it on the iFrame not making any server side call

Comment: here is the new thread I have created! https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342216/pdf-viewer-on-iframe-not-showing-download-and-print-button

Comment: @gs650x I will look at it give me sometime. I will respond there

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved this by making a change in the `postmessage`. Here's what I updated :

`this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(this.pdfData, window.location.origin);`

I hope this helps someone load pdf in lwc.

Comment: Thank you for posting your answer could you please help, with what is this.pdfData, is it blob or base64 or any other because I am still seeing the same issue.

Comment: @gs650x for me it is base64 data. You can post you code in a question, let me know if you do, I can see the code

Comment: Thank you, this would be really helpful, here is the thread that I have created. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342146/displaying-pdf-using-lightning-web-component?noredirect=1#comment503174_342146

Comment: here is the 2nd thread for saving the pdf as content document. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342163/saving-pdf-file-to-content-document-saves-as-black-pages