# How to create pdf using pdfjs library in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, renderas, libraries

I have a lwc in which I try to render a pdf. I have zipped the pdfjs library and added this as a static resource. In my template I can call the library as following:

```
        <iframe id="pdfFrame" src="/resource/pdfjs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" width="100%" height="100%" class="pdfFrame"
            onload={generatePdf}></iframe>
```

In my javascript controller I cant seem to create the pdf since the console.log only debugs the first "Alert 1"

**Javascript**

```
import {LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';
import {loadScript} from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import PDFJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfjs';

export default class JspdfDemo extends LightningElement {


    @track isModalOpen = false;  
    openModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = true;
       // this.generatePdf();
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }
    submitDetails() {
        this.isModalOpen = false;
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, PDFJS)
        ]);
    }

        generatePdf() {
            console.log('alert 1');
            const { PDFjs } = window.pdfjs;
            console.log('alert 2');
            const doc = new PDFjs({
            encryption: {
                userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
            }
        });
        console.log('alert 3');
        doc.text('Hello World!', 20, 20);
        var base = doc.output('datauristring').split(',')[1];
        console.log('alert 4');
        this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(base, window.location.origin);
        console.log('base: ' + base);
        console.log('doc: ' + doc);
        console.log('alert 5');
        }
}
```

I do not get an error. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE after adding a try catch

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'PDFjs' of 'window.pdfjs' as it is undefined.

Comment: wrap the whole code of generatePdf in a try-catch block. It will give you the specific errors.

Comment: Check this detailed answer, it may help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343331/how-to-render-a-pdf-generated-with-jspdf-in-a-lwc

Comment: @MukulMahawariya I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'PDFjs' of 'window.pdfjs' as it is undefined.

Comment: print window object in the console and search for pdfjs. You might be calling the wrong name or it's not yet initialized.

Comment: @SarojBera I have ideed looked at this example. Thee issue in this ticked is that the code is not consistend its using a different library jspdf and pdfjs between template and controller

Comment: Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, PDFJS)
        ]).then(()=>{
console.log('loaded');
});

you can also load the JS in connectedCallBack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who bumpes into this

```
  <iframe id="pdfFrame" src="/resource/pdfjs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" width="100%" height="100%" class="pdfFrame"
            onload={generatePdf}></iframe>
```

Is calling the pdfjs library which contains viewer.html.

const { PDFjs } = window.jspdf;
Note: jspdf instead of pdfjs is calling jspdf library that resolves error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'PDFjs' of 'window.pdfjs

Comment: Are you saying here that even though the library name is `pdfjs`, the `window` call has to be to `jspdf`?