# jsPDF is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf

Trying to generate PDF with JSPDF library but getting below error message when I'm trying to preview the PDF through Community or record pages in salesforce.

> Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'jsPDF' of 'window.jspdf'
> as it is undefined

Here is the code I have written in my LWC

```
import jsPDF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jsPDF';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jsPDF)
        ]);
    }

generate() {
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'in', 'letter');
        //Sets the text color setTextColor(ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4) 
        doc.setTextColor(100);
    doc.save("abc.pdf");
    }
```

Looks like it's failing on `const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;` this line and returning the above error.

Do you guys have any clue about this? Has anyone got jsPDF working in LWC?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create pdf using pdfjs library in lwc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393480/how-to-create-pdf-using-pdfjs-library-in-lwc)

Comment: No @identigral, Tried both but no luck.. Still getting Error TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'jsPDF' of 'window.jspdf' as it is undefined

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this [JSPDF](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.3.1/jspdf.umd.min.js) lib and [AutoTable](https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.5.14/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js) lib

Load script in render callback like below

```
jsPdfInitialized = false;

renderedCallback() {
    if (this.jsPdfInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.jsPdfInitialized = true;
    loadScript(this, jsPDFScript)
        .then(() => {
            loadScript(this, jsPDFAutoTableScript);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            throw error;
        });
}
```