# How to pass data from javascript controller to iframe in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, iframe, renderas, preview

I am trying to pass a pdf as a preview to an Iframe in LWC.
Note: a preview, not showing an existing pdf

I followed following example:
[How to render a PDF generated with jsPDF in a LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/343331/how-to-render-a-pdf-generated-with-jspdf-in-a-lwc)

How do I pass the data to the iframe?

1. I call the viewer as follows:

```
    <iframe id="iframe" src="/resource/pdfjs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" width="100%" height="100%" class="iframe"
                           onload={generatePdf}></iframe>
```

This renders an pdf example of the pdfjs library according tho the thread example

2. To create a pdf I do the following as in the thread:

```
    const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
            const pdf = new jsPDF({
                encryption: {
                    userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
                }
            });
            pdf.text("Hello World", 20, 20);  
           console.log(pdf.output('datauristring'));
            var base = pdf.output('datauristring').split(',')[1];
            console.log(base);
           this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(base, 
           window.location.origin);
    
    console.log('PDF: ' + pdf.output('datauristring'));
```

This renders a pdf tested with: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf

How do I pass the generated pdf to the iframe instead of the pdf of the library?

UPDATE

It seems unescape is deprecated so had to replace it with decodeURI. I end up with an empty Iframe.

**url debug**

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

This creates a pdf testing with: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf

**blob debug:**

```
[object Blob]
```

**this.objectURL debug:**

```
{baseurl}/4c84f9c4-2ebc-4ffc-a7e6-f9f8d5c6d37a
```

My Iframe stays empty no errors from catch

Comment: If you are dealing with Base64 encoded PDFs in LWC, please have a look at the following post which shows how to render them in an iFrame: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-display-and-download-base64-encoded-pdf-documents-with-lightning-web-components-d4a10c7fa4c3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem and followed below steps -

You need to convert the pdf to base64.
convert base64 to a data Uri.

Pass the data Uri as a source to iframe.

```
import jsPDF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jspdf';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class IframeQuestion extends LightningElement {

  connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, jsPDF).then(() => {
                console.log("JS loaded");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error " + error);
            })
        ]);
    }

  handleClick(event) {
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
            encryption: {
                userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
            }
        });
        pdf.text("Hello World", 20, 20);
        let base64 = pdf.output('datauristring');
        console.log(pdf.output('datauristring'));
        var base = pdf.output('datauristring').split(',')[1];
        console.log(base);
        this.template.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage(base,
            window.location.origin);

        console.log('PDF: ' + pdf.output('datauristring'));

        let blob = this.dataURItoBlob(base64);
        this.objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    }


  dataURItoBlob(dataURI)
  {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;

    if(dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++)
    {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type: mimeString});
  }

}
```

**HTML-**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow" title="Hello" icon-name="standard:account">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Show PDF" title="pdf" onclick={handleClick}>
        </lightning-button>
        <iframe id="iframe" src={objectURL} width="100%" height="100%" class="iframe" onload={generatePdf}></iframe>
    </lightning-card>

</template>
```

You can download the **jspdf.umd.min.js** library from https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF/tree/master/dist and upload it as a static resource as **jsPDF**

Please comment if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I end up with an empty Iframe. I updated my question with the results.

Comment: Did you have time to look at my update?

Comment: @Thomas I have updated the code and added one more function which is working fine for me. Try the code as it is, it'll definitely generate the pdf on the button click.

Comment: Could you share the jspdf library you used for this an how your import line is written I get the following error: Cannot destructure property 'jsPDF' of 'window.jspdf' as it is undefined.

Comment: Added the link to download the JS in the answer.