# PDF viewer on iFrame not showing download and print button

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have the below HTML

```
<iframe id="pdfFrame" src="/resource/pdfjs/web/viewer.html" width="100%" height="100%" class="pdfFrame"
        onload={generatePdf}></iframe>
```

JS:

```
    generatePdf() {
        const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
        const doc = new jsPDF({
            encryption: {
                userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
            }
        });
        
        doc.text('Hello World!', 20, 20);

    var base = doc.output('datauristring').split(',')[1];

    this.template.querySelector('iframe')
        .contentWindow.postMessage(base, window.location.origin);
}
```

It renders as below

[image]

There is no download or print button available on the PDF viewer.
could someone please suggest how to get these buttons on the screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the file based on a link, you can add a custom lightning button and then add below code that should download the file for you.

```
<lightning-button variant="brand" label="Download" title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

in your JS :

```
handleClick(event){
    let downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
                downloadLink.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                downloadLink.href = "data:application/octet-stream;base64,"+this.pdfData; // PDF base64Data
                downloadLink.download = "filename.pdf";//modify as you need
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                downloadLink.remove();
}
```

this is what I could make it work from StachExchange only, I am having hard time finding that thread to link here.

Also, for Print you dont need to do anything differently, using cmd + p in mac works for me to get print pop up.

Comment: @gs650x did it work for you?

Comment: I am sorry, I am in IST hours, I just saw your answer, I have tried this, thank you for your kind help but our application is mainly focused on mobile users, above works as expected on desktop but doesn't work on salesforce 1 mobile app, could you please suggest similar workaround which will work on mobile phones?

Comment: I dont have experience with mobile app since it will be much different than this approach. You can however do this, a dirty approach will be to Save the PDF to contentDocument (the one you are displaying to the users) - get the DownloadableUrl from contentDocument object - delete the file from ContentDocument once user downloads it.

Comment: yes, this is the only approach, I could think of as of now, thank you for your help.

Comment: By any chance can you please help me with the jsPDF-autotable I have Imported it but still it throws autoTable is not a function

Comment: Instead of hard coding the 'Hello World!', Is it possible to pass a section of the currently viewing lwc page to generate pdf?